# man page with complex name

Tags: manpage

I'm writing man pages for my Tcl library, one file per command. Command names contain `::`, for example `mypackage::mycommand`.

I'd like to call proper man page by following command: `man mypackage::mycommand`. For this purpose corresponding man file is called `mypackage::mycommand.n` (I'm using "n" section of manual).

It works in Linux, but it does not in Windows, because some applications cannot properly work with files containing ":" in names. So I'd like to rename man files, say to `mypackage_mycommand.n`.

Question: is it possible to call my manual by `man mypackage::mycommand`, if corresponding man file has different name?

Thanks.